# What is the best way to create pie graphs and other animated dynamic info graphics?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the best way to create pie graphs and other animated dynamic info graphics?

Should I look into js libs like paper.js or should I create my own using minimal js and css3?

Examples are really what I'd like to see. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of javascript libraries out there which will do this for you. There certainly isn't any need to be rolling your own code.

If you do want to write your own, be aware that to get the kind of effects available with some of the libraries will take a lot more than minimal js code. Sure you could write a very basic script that draws pie segments in a fairly small amount of code, it won't have the animations or dynamic properties you'd get from using a library. And most libraries really aren't that big considering how much they do.

My favourite library for this sort of thing is [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/), along with it's graphing sister library [g.Raphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/).

The beauty of Raphael is that it makes it very easy to produce quite complex graphics, including some very nice animated graphs. See the examples on the site above, which includes pie charts.

It's all Javascript-based so you can update it on the fly.

In addition, Raphael scores over other similar libraries in that it works flawlessly even in older versions of IE (as far back as IE6!), as it uses SVG on modern browsers, and falls back to VML for old versions of IE.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Hal50000: In October 2015 when I wrote this answer, it was easily the best library of it's type, particularly because of it's compatibility with old IE versions. Five years on, that latter point is much less of an issue and other libraries have come along that can do similar things more elegantly. I still consider Raphael to be a very good piece of software though; it broke a lot of ground for others to follow, and it's still usable and respected today.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, Google Chart is a good option: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Comment: Do they update and animate in real-time? Are they fully customizable?

Comment: There is a chart gallery with many examples: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery.html, and the API is very easy

Answer (score 1):

I have used and actually liked this library: http://www.highcharts.com/

There are quite a few other options though - I see no point in reinventing the wheel.